# AngularJS page refreshes to homepage issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

I am building a study application in AngularJS and I am facing an issue that when ever I refresh the page from any location it redirects to homepage, for example: I am on `localhost/angular/inner-page/page-id` and I refresh the page then first it redirects to `localhost/angular/index.html` which is the template file and then it redirects to `localhost/angular`.

here is the code:

```
// application
var myApp = angular.module("firstApp", ["ngRoute"])
// routes
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    var baseUrl = "../includes/016-routing/";

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        "templateUrl": baseUrl + "home.html",
        "controller": "homeController"
    }).when("/courses", {
        "templateUrl": baseUrl + "courses.html",
        "controller": "coursesController"
    }).when("/students", {
        "templateUrl": baseUrl + "students.html",
        "controller": "studentsController"
    }).when("/student/:id", {
        "templateUrl": baseUrl + "student.html",
        "controller": "studentController"
    }).otherwise({
        "redirectTo": "/home"
    });
})
// controllers
.controller("homeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.heading = "Home Page";
}).controller("coursesController", function($scope) {
    $scope.heading = "Courses";
    $scope.courses = [
        "PHP",
        "CSS",
        "SCSS",
        "MySQL",
        "JavaScript",
        "jQuery",
        "AngularJs"
    ];
}).controller("studentsController", function($scope) {
    $scope.heading = "Students";
    $scope.students = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Parminder Singh"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kanwaljeet Kaur"
    }];
}).controller("studentController", function($scope, $routeParams) {
    // variables
    var id = ($routeParams.id > 0 || $routeParams.id) ? ($routeParams.id - 1) : 0;
    var $students = [{
        "name": "Parminder Singh",
        "age": 34,
        "profession": "PHP Developer",
        "designation": "Sr. PHP Developer"
    }, {
        "name": "Kanwaljeet Kaur",
        "age": 28,
        "profession": "House Wife",
        "designation": "Home Ministry"
    }];

    $scope.heading = $students[id].name;
    $scope.student = $students[id];
});
```

Comment: Do you have defined the routing to `inner-page/page-id`? If not, it redirects you to the `/home` because the routing "path" does not match to any of your defined one.

Comment: Does your server support html5 mode? Server side requires URL rewriting on the server - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side

Comment: @Batajus, its just examples. The real urls are different.

Comment: I am learning AngularJs so all the code is on my local not on any server. Also I have done the URL rewriting and its working fine, its just this refresh issue which I could not find any solution.

Comment: Hey guys, the issue is solved. It turned out be .htaccess which was causing the issue. Here is what I did:
`RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost/anguler/routing/index.html [NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]`